# Fail to read an image with opencv in C++ when call it in matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I'm going to load an image using cv::imread in a C++ program. When I run it directly in the terminal, it works well. But when I call it in matlab with "system" or "dos", it always return empty Mat without any error.

I work in MacOS Sierra 10.12.4. OpenCV version is 2.4.13. Matlab version is R2015b. Could anyone help me? Please send me some suggestions.

For example, I write a test code.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main(){
    std::string  path = "/Users/zhefeng.wzf/0001.jpg";
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(path);

    if(image.empty()){
        printf("Cannot load image:%s\n",path.c_str());
    }else{
        printf("Load the image successfully.\n");
        cv::imshow("image",image);
        cv::waitKey();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and then I compile it with

> g++ readImg.cpp -o readImg `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

When I run it in the terminal, 
[It works well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9c6u.png)

But when I run it in the matlab,
[it failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxBZt.png)

Comment: what path are you passing to the `cv::imread()` in C++ program ? Try with full qualified path.

Comment: I passed the absolute path to cv::imread(). I'm sure that it can find the file.

Comment: The path is /Users/zhefeng.wzf/ I think the issue is the name of the last folder, it has .wzf which may cause problems, change the name of the folder and try again

Comment: I changed the name folder and it still failed. :(

Answer (score 1):

It failed because Matlab uses its own OpenCV dylib which is incompatible with your app's version. Just use `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`(equals to `LD_PRELOAD` in Linux) to force Matlab to use your app's OpenCV version.

You can find your app's version with `otool`(equals to `ldd` in linux)

```
otool -L /path/to/your/app/app
```

This will give all dylibs your app uses. Open your Matlab with

```
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="path/to/dylib.dylib:another/path/dylib2.dylib" /path/to/matlab
```

Run your code and this should work.

Comment: Wow! Your solution solved my problem perfectly. Thanks a lot! Matlab has its own opencv libiries in `/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64`, which may be conflicted with system opencv.